# Firebase + custom backend: Should I retrieve jwt token on Client before every http request?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, jwt, firebase-admin

I'm creating an Android app where I want to use Firebase only for authentication and my own backend for the rest.

I've been following this [Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens) where i found out how to retrieve a jwt token. I managed to send the token to my rest api via POST method and verify it there using php JWT Firebase library and now I'm a little bit stuck.

When is the correct time to retrieve the token?
Do I:

1. Retrieve the token upon the start of the app (or register / log in etc.), store it in variable so I don't have to retrieve it again and then send the token with every http request to authorize the user.
2. Retrieve the token once and store it in maybe SharedPreferences.
3. Before every http request, I retrieve the token so it's fresh and I can be sure it's valid.
4. Validate the token only upon the start of the app and if it's valid, extract the user id from the token in client, store it in variable and use the ID in future http requests to know what user is making the requests.

I'm most intrigued to use the third option, however the code for retrieving the token is pretty long and I can imagine my code would get messy pretty fast. Also the fourth option sound great on paper for me, but I feel like It's really bad idea in terms of security.

I'm scared to use the first and second option, because the token expiration time. I can figure out the token is invalid on the backend, but then I would have to inform the client it's invalid, generate new token and then make the request again, which seems very complicated for me.

**Are there some common practices I should be following? Is one of my examples at least a little right or am I completely wrong?**

I'm very new in this area of development in my new job and can't find much information about how should I proceed in situations like this. I will be very thankful for any answer!

Answer (score 2):

You should get the ID token prior to each HTTP call, and include it in the requests. You don't have to necessarily refresh the ID token each time (i.e. no need to pass `true` to `getIdToken()`). In fact that is likely to make the app slower.

Options 1 and 2 are difficult to implement correctly, as ID tokens change every hour or so. Option 4 is not secure.